# npm start not working and gulp is deprecate?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

First post here. Sorry its so long.

I am trying to contribute towards an open source project on Github. I successfully downloaded and cloned the project. I am using Windows 10 and Node.js version v8.11.2

When I run npm start in my command prompt I get the following error:

```js
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ashley Clarke\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-06T18_34_45_556Z-debug.log
```

So I tried to make sure was connected to the gulp server in my Node.js command prompt.

And got this error:

```js
C:\Users\Ashley Clarke>gulp server
[10:59:43] Local gulp not found in ~
[10:59:43] Try running: npm install gulp
```

Then when I ran npm install gulp this popped up.

```js
C:\Users\Ashley Clarke>npm install gulp -g
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
C:\Users\Ashley Clarke\AppData\Roaming\npm\gulp -> C:\Users\Ashley Clarke\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js
+ gulp@3.9.1
added 255 packages in 45.834s
```

I tried to go to https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5 but it talked about plugins. I guess I'm struggling with understanding what I need to do to connect to the gulp server so I can contribute to this open source project. Thanks!!
P.S tried to add pictures. Thanks in advance.

Comment: run `npm install gulp` inside the project folder.

Comment: Hi @MukeshSharma thanks for the response. I am still getting the same error. Im thinking maybe the project is just outdated